# Как расположить элементы по бокам header (как на макете)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Задача: расположить эти блоки (адрес и номер телефона) по бокам header'а за краями ограничителя, как показано в макете.
Кроме того, нужно сделать их адаптивными, чтобы они скрывались на маленьких экранах, где под них недостаточно места.

Я знаю, что это возможно, но не могу додуматься. Гуглить пробовал, но ничего не нашёл.
[image: розовые линии это ограничители контента]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте этот вариант

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left,
.right,
.center {
  height: inherit;
}

.left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #937343;
}

.center {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #647283;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #821749;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .left,
  .right {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как самый простой вариант - задать им абсолютное позиционирование относительно всего блока с категориями. А потом медиа-запросом прятать.

Либо, но тут не факт, надо протестить,  флексами сделать блок, блоку с категориями задать ширину контейнера, а родительскому блоку `justify-content: space-between`.
Тогда у тебя, по идеи, блок с категориями должен встать по центру, как в макете, а контакты по бокам.